# What happens when a server needs to change the cipher during an established TLS session

Tags: tls

I have read the following excellent post [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) but unfortunately it does not clear up one question I have.

If during an established TLS session the server becomes busy and needs to renegotiate the cipher being used what exactly happens, assuming secure renegotiation is in place.

Does the server initiate a new full handshake, does it simply use session resumption?

Comment: Why does the server need a new cipher when it gets busy? I'm pretty sure that this does not help with the busy part because doing the new handshake needed to get a new cipher and key is more expensive than continuing with the cheap symmetric encryption with the existing cipher.

Comment: To add to what Steffen and Gowenfawr have already pointed out, I'm not aware of any TLS implementation that would initiate a change in the cipher being used after a handshake is completed, or even choose an initial cipher suite (change the priority order, effectively) based on how "busy" it is.

Comment: It is actually part of an exam question that a work colleague was asked as part of a cyber security certification he is taking in college. 
No other information supplied in the question as to why the server would be busy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session Resumption will re-use the previously negotiated cipher spec, so if you need to renegotiate a different cipher, you will need a new handshake.  To quote [RFC 5246 section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7) (emphasis mine):

> The Handshake Protocol is responsible for negotiating **a session, which
> consists of the following items**:
>
> ...(session identifier, peer certificate, compression method)...
>
> cipher spec: Specifies the pseudorandom function (PRF) used to generate keying
> material, the bulk data encryption algorithm (such as null, AES, etc.)
> and the MAC algorithm (such as HMAC-SHA1).  It also defines
> cryptographic attributes such as the mac_length.  (See Appendix A.6
> for formal definition.)
>
> ...(master secret, is resumable)...
>
> These items are then used to create security parameters for use by the
> record layer when protecting application data.  Many connections can
> be instantiated **using the same session through the resumption feature**
> of the TLS Handshake Protocol.